# how to write method for sequential search through array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am writing a java method which runs through an array and if a value is present, then it returns the index of the value. It is not compiling, but I don't know what part of my code isn't comprehensive.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Lab26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public static int simpleSearch(int[] nums, int value) {
        int nul = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The complier error message should tell you

Comment: It does, I just don't know how to fix it. My problem is that if the value is not found, nothing should be returned.

Comment: Add `return -1;` at the end of method.

Comment: @saka1029 that looks like the the issue, consider making an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

What if `if (nums[i] == value)` is never satisfied? You will not return anything but the method signature expects you to return an `int`.

in `simpleSearch` method, return an integer at the end.